# How to remove routes until a specific page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am trying to Navigate to a specific page while removing the routes before that page.

```
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                Routes.pageIWantToGo,
                (Route<dynamic> route) {
                  return route is RemoveUntilPage;
                },
                arguments: <String, dynamic>{
                  'sample': sample,
                },
              );
```

Where RemoveUntilPage is the Widget of the Page.

But this code is not working as expected, the issue I face is all the routes are being removed, instead of the expected only a few. it's removing all the pages until `root`.

Thanks for the help. A Code example is also welcome.

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, all the routes are being removed. instead of expected only few. it's working like pushNamedAndRemoveUntilRoot(). 

Hope it helps.